# How can I compare each item of each list each other? etc. ['3','3', '1', '0.05'] ['5', '2', '4', '0.05'] if 3 equal to 5?

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop, compare

[This is currently what it is now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nj11Y.png)

So I want to compare the first item of the triangle ['3', '3', '1', '0.05'] which is 3 and then take it to compare the first item of the next triangle ['5', '2', '4', '0.05'] etc. if 3 == 5：how can i do it

Comment: What does *compare* mean? Please be more specific, and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: you should include the code itself in the post, and not a picture of it

Comment: check 3 if equal to 5 which is the first item of the first triangle if equal to the first item of the second triangle.

Answer (score 1):

```
L1 = ['3','3', '1', '0.05'] 
L2 = ['5', '2', '4', '0.05']

L1 = [float(i) for i in L1]
L2 = [float(i) for i in L2]

for a,b in zip(L1, L2):
    if a==b:
        print(a, '=', b)
    else:
        print(a, '!=', b)
```